# Xamarin Forms change Tabbar to Toolbar using Shell Menu

Tags: android, ios, visual-studio, xaml, xamarin.forms

I am working on a cross-plat app and was wondering, how to change the bottom tabbar into a toolbar? Or give it the function of a toolbar (where I am not navigating to seperate pages upon clicking an item on the toolbar). I have added a 'ContentPage' object to the Shell page in the tabbar, but it still navigates to that page (it's rendered as a seperate page and any elements I place in it are rendered on the new page). I want to keep the top Toolbar and Flyout menu.

Here is the Xaml code from the Shell page.

```
<TabBar>
    <Tab Title="Browse" Icon="tab_feed.png">
        <ShellContent ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate local:ItemsPage}" />
    </Tab>
    <Tab Title="About" Icon="tab_about.png">
        <ShellContent ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate local:AboutPage}" />
    </Tab>
    <contentpage>
            <Label text="foo"/>
          </contentpage>
</TabBar>
```

I don't know if I can continue to use the 'Tabbar item or not, but if I can, I don't know what element to insert to just perform actions (no navigation).

Edit 02/05/2020
You can remove the Tabbar by just putting one Tab in it (it then disappears). You can add a makeshift Toolbar by putting a FlexLayout or Grid inside a Grid and setting RowDefinitions (87* and 13*) in the outer Grid, then set inner element to second row (Grid.Row="1"). Grid displays the items in order their added.

I found the fastest way to create an app with drawer, top and bottom navigation bars I'd with a MasterDetail app. You can add custom content to the Drawer and MainPage (and top and bottom navigation bars)easier this way (no fooling with tabs). You can exclude any files you don't need and/or any features you don't need (drawer/bars).

Comment: Hi , do you mean the `Flyout Item` be tapped ? If you want to change color , there are some methods in Shell can be used such as [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/shell/configuration#set-page-colors) or using `Syle` inside Xaml . You can explain your question with image ,that will be helpful , and if this question be solved , you'd better create a new one to ask , there will be more people to see it .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you really insist on that you could do whatever you intend to do on the `OnAppearing` method of each tab page and then communicate to the `TabBar` to switch back to the original page which would be first and wouldn't have no title and icon.

Speaking of that this would require a lot of work, would look very ugly, and likely this would be the worst implementation of the toolbar ever. However if you insist on using the TabBar that is probably the only possible way.

And you can't skip the navigation as it is impossible with the native TabBar on iOS which makes it impossible for TabBar on Xamarin.Forms too.

There isn't any Xamarin.Forms element that would act like that, however you may place several buttons in the `StackLayout` at the bottom of the page.

Comment: I did something that's worked thus far; I changed the <ShellContent - Control Template> to the same page for each 'Tab' item. This works on keeping the same page open like buttons on a Toolbar, but I don't know what to add to make the Tab 'buttons' do things now.

Comment: @Code_Student09 that will work if pages can’t scroll, change their content etc.

Comment: You mentioned placing buttons in a StackLayout at the bottom of the page to get them to show up, what page did you mean?

Comment: @Code_Student09 you create the content page and pose it there it will look like that.

Comment: I added the buttons to a Grid element at the bottom of the page, set the HeighRequest to 60 to mimic a toolbar and that mostly works, but now how do I set the absolute position of a button (or imagebutton)? Setting a Grid.ColumnDefinitions element on the page caused an error (cannot contain direct content).